# Why is my _subscribers data view returning different results for email address?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, data-views

I have both MC and SC connected together using the MC Connector. I have noticed a data inconsistency issue when creating an automation to update Email Addresses in my All Subscribers list.

When I the `_subscribers` data view for a Subscriber, I get `exampleemail@mail.com`, using the same subscriber key when I search for it manually via Email Studio > Subscribers > All Subscribers > Search via sub key the email address is `address2@mail.com`.

I've searched for the Contact in Contact Builder, searching by the Contact Key (Subscriber Key) returns TWO records, both of which have the same Contact ID (not sure if this is a UI bug or an unrelated data issue) but I checked both records as they have email `address2@mail.com`.

So I'm not sure  why only _subscribers returns a different email address. Can anyone advise?

Comment: the _subscriber data view should match 'All subs' it should not match anything with contact builder/ all contacts

Comment: But that’s the problem, it doesn’t which is what I’m trying to figure out.